# grunt-contrib-watch trigger document ready

Tags: gruntjs, watch, livereload

I have grunt-contrib-watch working, but if I change javascript under jQuery(document).ready I have to reload the page.

Is it possible to have the watch trigger the document ready event so I do not have to refresh the page?

Comment: I am confused. At what point did `livereload` (which is what, I assume, you are using) **did not reload the page** upon change?

Comment: /me is also confused... the `watch` task waits for changes to a file, and then kicks off a grunt task. Perhaps things would be clearer if you posted your `Gruntfile` (or at least the `watch` section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working. I did not have my browser plugin enabled. It now refreshes the page if javascript is changed. Specifically I was working on jqplot. Apologizes for confusion.